# Find another linearly independent solution of $2$-order ODE: $x'' + 2tx'+(1-\frac 3 {4t^2}) x = 0$ defined on $(0,\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find another linearly independent solution of $2$-order ODE: $x^{''} + 2tx^{'}+(1-\frac 3 {4t^2}) x = 0$ defined on $(0,\infty)$.

I've the following 2'nd order ODE: $$x'' + 2tx'+\left(1-\frac 3 {4t^2}\right) x = 0$$

defined on $(0,\infty)$ and I've found the solution by trial and error: $t^{-1/2}$.

I want to find another linearly independent solution defined on $(0,\infty)$. How can this be done ?

I've used the ansatz: $at^p$, but as far as I can see this implies $p=-1/2$ and $a \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: did you treat $a$ as a function of $t,$  not as a constant?

Comment: I did threat $a$ as a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look for solution of the form $x = at^{-1/2}.$ then 
$x^\prime = a^\prime t^{-1/2} -\frac{1}{2}at^{-3/2}, x^{\prime \prime}=a^{\prime \prime}t^{1/2} -a^\prime t^{-3/2} + \frac{3}{4}at^{-5/2}.$ substitute all these in $\begin{align}Lx &= x^{\prime\prime} + 2tx^\prime +(1-\frac{3}{4t^2})x \\
&=  a^{\prime \prime}t^{1/2} -a^\prime t^{-3/2} + \frac{3}{4}at^{-5/2}+2t( a^\prime t^{-1/2} -\frac{1}{2}at^{-3/2})+ (1-\frac{3}{4t^2})at^{-1/2}\\
&= a^{\prime \prime}t^{1/2} -a^\prime t^{-3/2}+2a^\prime t^{1/2} = t^{1/2}\left( a^{\prime \prime} +a^\prime(2-\frac{1}{t})\right)\\
\end{align}$

we need to solve the first order differential equation $$ \frac{a^{\prime \prime}}{a^\prime} +(2-\frac{1}{t}) = 0$$ which has a particular solution $$a^\prime = te^{-2t}, a = \int_0^t te^{-2t}\, dt = -\frac{1}{2}te^{-2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2t},x = at^{-1/2}$$ is the second solution of $Lx =0.$

Comment: What is $L$ ? And do you assume $a' \neq 0$ ?

Comment: @user111854, don't worry about $L$. i used it to denote a linear operation on $x.$ you need to assume $a$ now is a function of $t$ and determine $a$ or $a^\prime$. i made a mistake i should go back and correct it. see the edit in a minute.

Comment: Why is the quotient of two differentials $a'' / a'$ a first order equation ?

Comment: if you take the derivative of $\ln a^\prime,$ you get $\frac{a^{\prime \prime}}{a^\prime}$  that is $\ln(a^\prime)$ is the antiderivative of the quotient.

Comment: Ahh, thank you @abel !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduction of order formula:

$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int \frac{e^{-\int P(x)dx}}{y_1^2(x)} dx$$

where $y_1$ is one solution, $P(x)$ is the coefficient of $y'$, in your case, $2t$.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you already have an answer you are happy with. Let me still add this answer to provide another tool for this kind of problems, namely the Wronskian.

From the theory we know that we have two linearly independent solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ to the differential equation
$$
x''+2tx'+\Bigl(1-\frac{3}{4t^2}\Bigr)x=0. 
$$
You have found one of them, $x_1(t)=c_1t^{-1/2}$. We look for the second one, $x_2$.

Define the Wronskian,
$$
W(t)=x_1x_2'-x_1'x_2.\tag{1}
$$
Differentiating, we find that
$$
W'(t)=x_1x_2''-x_1''x_2.
$$
Now, using that $x_1$ and $x_2$ solves your differential equation, we can replace $x_1''$ and $x_2''$ by the lower order terms, (do the calculation!)
$$
W'(t)=\cdots=2tW(t).
$$
Hence $W(t)=ce^{t^2}$. Inserting this into $(1)$, we should find $x_2$ such that
$$
ce^{t^2}=t^{-1/2}x_2'+\frac{1}{2}t^{-3/2}x_2.
$$
This differential equation can be written
$$
x_2'+\frac{1}{2t}x_2=ct^{1/2}e^{t^2}.
$$
We multiply with the integrating factor $t^{1/2}$, and get
$$
\bigl(t^{1/2}x_2\bigr)'=cte^{t^2}.
$$
Integrating, we get
$$
t^{1/2}x_2=\frac{c}{2}e^{t^2}+d,
$$
so
$$
x_2=\frac{c}{2}t^{-1/2}e^{t^2}+dt^{-1/2}.
$$
The second part is already present in $x_1$. We let
$$
x_2=c_2t^{-1/2}e^{t^2}.
$$
As a final note, we find that the Wronskian becomes $W(t)=2c_1c_2e^{t^2}\neq 0$.